# Copy keyframes from one mesh and paste onto another?

Tags: animation, objects, keyframes

I know this is similar to other questions, but i cant find an answer.

I have a mesh with keyframes, and it works perfectly. I just created another one, and it needs the same keyframes as mesh 1. It might not even be possible, but if it is, any helps would be great. Thanks!

Comment: I found an alternative in my case, but I'll leave the question up for others with the problem.

Comment: what do you mean exactly by "it needs the same keyframes as mesh"? Do you mean you want to give the same animation to a new object? In that case you just need to go in the Dopesheet/Action Editor mode, select your new object, and select the animation you want in the dropdown menu...

Comment: Yes, I mean have the second mesh have the same animation as the first.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give the same animation to another object, here are some basics:

- Let say you have given a Location animation to your cube object.
- If you want to give the same animation to a second object (cone), you'll need to go in the *Dopesheet/Action Editor* mode, and scroll in the dropdown menu until you find the cube animation. You can also select the cone, then the cube, and <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Make Links/Animation Data*.
- The problem is that once you'll give the same animation, the cone (its origine point) will be at the exact same point as the cube. If this is what you want, everything's ok. If it not, here are two ways to change the position of the cone, you can either:
- At frame 1, parent your cone to an empty and move the empty wherever you want in the 3D scene, the cone will follow the empty and it won't overlap with the cube anymore.
- Or use the *Delta Transform* parameters in the *Properties* panel > *Object* > *Delta Transform*. It will allow you to offset the position of the cone object on the X, Y or Z axis, so that it won't overlap anymore.
- Another thing: if you want to delay the animation of the cone, i.e. if you want the cone to have the exact same animation than the cube but you want it to happen before or after the animation of the cube, you can  use the *NLA* editor, push down the strip on the track and move the strip it along the track where you want the action to happen.

[image]